# Having a list of strings represented in a database using ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

First of I am new to ORMLite. I would like my model class to have a field which is a list of strings, that would eventually hold a list of tags for my model object.
Which ORMLite annotations should I use?

Firstly I don't want to have a table of all tags, and then use the `@ForeignCollectionField`.
Also I thought of using the `@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE)` annotation, but it turns out that `List<String>` doesn't implement the `Serializable` interface.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, List doesn't implement `Serializable` but ArrayList certainly does as well as most of the common collection implementations.  But storing a huge list is probably not the best of doing this from a pure object model standpoint.

So why don't you want to have a table of all tags?  That's the best way from a pure model standpoint.  It will require a 2nd query if you need them every time.  That's the way hibernate would store a list or array of tags.

---

After reading your comment @creen, I still think you *do* want a table of tags.  Your model class would then have:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
Collection<Tag> tags;
```

The `tags` table would *not* have a single tag named `"red"` with multiple model classes referring to it but multiple `"red"` entries.  It would look like:

```
model_id    name
1           "red"
1           "blue"
2           "red"
3           "blue"
3           "black"
```

Whenever you are removing the model object, you would first do a `tags.clear();` which would remove all of the tags associated with that model from the tags table.  You would not have to do any extra cleanup or anything.

Comment: The reason for not wanting a table of tags is that my data is frequently changing. Removing an object with tags, I would for every tag it has, need to query for other objects with the same tags, if none is found I can remove the tag for the tags table.
I think this is more work that what is needed for a simple list of tags.
But thanks for the heads-up on the Collections implementations.

Comment: Nice, I thought of the ForeignCollectionField as a ManyToMany relation, but as you put it, it is more like a OneToMany relation, which gives me peace to my mind :)
Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

No need to go for @ForeignCollectionField for simple String Array

Change your code

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE) 
List<String> users;
```

to

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
String[] users;
```

Database doesn't want to store dynamically grow able arrays. That is the reason it allows only static array like string[] and not List.

Answer (score 0):

I added two properties... one that gets written to the database as a csv string and the other that translates this:

```
[Ignore]
public List<string> Roles
{
    get
    {
        return new List<string>(RolesCsv.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
    }
    set
    {
        RolesCsv = string.Join(",", value);
    }
}
public string RolesCsv { get; set; }
```