# List<String> as a @ForeignCollectionField ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have in my model Class

```
List<String> _photo_array;
```

since I can put anotation on String Class is it a way to persist it using ormLite?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691507/storing-list-of-objects-using-datatype-serializable-in-ormlite-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997298/having-a-list-of-strings-represented-in-a-database-using-ormlite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> since I can put anotation on String Class is it a way to persist it using ormLite?

You are going to have to create an entity that wraps the `String`.  Something like:

```
 @DatabaseTable
 public class Photo {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     private int id;
     @DatabaseField
     private String photo;
     @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
     private Model model;
 }
```

Then your model class would have a `ForeignCollection` of these photos.

```
 @DatabaseTable
 public class Model {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     private int id;
     @ForeignCollectionField()
     private ForeignCollection<Photo> photos;
 }
```

See the [foreign collection example](http://ormlite.com/docs/example-foreign-collection).

Comment: I accept your answer even if I can't use it, my objects come from web services as json witch is parsed "easily" with gson in on line and I can't change the server side, the only think I can do is to change the parse (witch is factored)... any way thank you your answer still the best think to do :)

Comment: Best of luck @Simo.  Lot of people are having json <-> ormlite issues.  Common problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use one-to-many relations.

To persist one-to-many relations you can should use ForeignCollection. 
[Check the docu.](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection)

Other types of collections are not supported by ORMLite, as I know.

Another point is you need a back-reference in the referenced Object.
To mark a field as back-reference, use annotation @DatabaseField(foreign = true, ... )

For Scenario A(1) -> B(n)

```
class A {

   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = BaseColumns._ID)
   public int _id;

   @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
   public ForeignCollection<B> _photo_array;

}

class B {
   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = BaseColumns._ID)
   public int _id;

   @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, 
         foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignAutoCreate = true)
   public A a;
}
```

In this scenario A reference B in one-to-many way. If a will be loaded, all dependent B's will also be loaded (because of eager = true)

To save this structure you could use this way (i hope you have allready created ADao and BDao classes):

```
        final A a = ...;
        final ADao aDAO = ...;

        aDAO.createOrUpdate(a);

        final ArrayList<B> children = ...;
        final BDao bDAO = ...;
        for (final B b: children ) {
            bDAO.create(season);
        }
```

A and B including dependency will be stored. If you now try to get A from db you will also get all B's related to instance of A.